# Vue 3 mobile event listeners and swipe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

In Vue 3, I want to trigger a function when a user swipes left / right. (I made a calendar and interested in having months changed on swiping)

I found this package: https://github.com/robinrodricks/vue3-touch-events (npm install vue3-touch-events) but it's not working and I get the following errors:

and imported the relevant packages in main.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vue3TouchEvents from "vue3-touch-events";
```

and in public/index.html:

```
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robinrodricks/vue3-touch-events/master/index.js"></script>
```

after that, in main.js
If registered as:

```
createApp(App)
  .use(Vue3TouchEvents)
```

then I get the error: "Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component ..."
And the event won't be fired.

If registered as

```
Vue.use(Vue3TouchEvents);
```

then I get the error "export 'default' (imported as 'Vue') was not found in 'vue'"
And the event still won't be fired

What's wrong? How to implement it right or make a solution in another way?
(@starttouch and mobile event listeners seems to not be supported in Vue 3)

Answer (score 0):

**I Think You Installed It Wrong Way**

1. `npm cache clean --force`
2. `npm install vue3-touch-events`

Also Remove That script src line from index.html.
I Hope This Will Help Your Query.

Comment: Thank you :) but sadly it did not....

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem in this way, please note that only the function name needs to be passed

main.js

```
import Vue3TouchEvents from "vue3-touch-events";

const app = createApp(App);
app.use(Vue3TouchEvents);
```

Component.vue

```
// script setup
const doSwipeLeft = () => {
    // some code
};
const doSwipeRight = () => {
    // some code
};

//template
<Component            
    v-touch:swipe.left="doSwipeLeft"
    v-touch:swipe.right="doSwipeRight"
>
```